# remove a legend dimple.js

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

I have a dimple.js graph with a single series, but I do not want to display all the legend keys in the series. Is there some way to select what legend keys I want to have displayed?

I searched the dimple.js API and Stack Overflow, but found no answers.

Comment: Could you create a dummy series that only has the points for the legend keys you want and then use `dimple.legend.series` to display the dummy series? If you can post up what you're working with it might be easier to help as well.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I am interpreting your question right. If you are looking for a way to remove elements from the legend or remove the legend entirely, then Yes, there is a simple solution to your problem.

```
myLegend.series = [myFirstSeries, mySecondSeries];
```

By default all chart series will be included, however this statement allows you to pick particular ones.

For example,

```
myFirstSeries = myChart.addSeries("Key1", dimple.plot.bar);
mySecondSeries= myChart.addSeries("Key2", dimple.plot.bar);
myThirdSeries= myChart.addSeries("Key3", dimple.plot.bar);
myFourthSeries= myChart.addSeries("Key4", dimple.plot.bar);

myLegend.series = [myFirstSeries, mySecondSeries]; 
//Displays only the first two keys in the legend
```

This should solve your problem.

You can find a lot of additional information regarding the legend here [dimple.legend](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.legend#series)